# Cannot parse a JSON document enveloped in a TSV file

Tags: java, gson

I have a tsv file where the 4th column is json output from a webservice. For example:

```
{"title":"GloMop","fullText":"home page; file:/C:\\unzipped\\pythia—demo—pages\\pythia\\index.html, White Paper. Dated Jul. 6, 2005,.(Downloaded Jul. 6, 2005), 11 pgs"}
```

I am reading the tsv file and when I read 4th column I see below output:

```
{"title":"GloMop","fullText":"home page; file:/C:\unzipped\pythia—demo—pages\pythia\index.html, White Paper. Dated Jul. 6, 2005,.(Downloaded Jul. 6, 2005), 11 pgs"}
```

and parse as json using `gson` I see `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException`.

To avoid this, I tried to escape `\` and added `replace("\\", "\\\\")` to 4th column which was read successfully.

But, now the problem is that, there is another json string as below which fails with `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException`:

```
{"person":[{"initials":"J.","name":"HEINZERING"}],"fullText":"R\\NTGENSTRAHLEN, Nr. Seiten 34-41, DE; u.a.; \"Technische Fortschritte in der NMR-Tomographie"}
```

```
        try {
            json.setInputReference(gson.fromJson(rowJsonMappingJson, Structured.class));
        } catch (JsonParseException exception) {
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(rowJsonMappingJson.replace("\\", "\\\\")));
            reader.setLenient(true);
            json.setInputReference(gson.fromJson(reader, Structured.class));
        }
```

I have tried even escaping the same using below code for json string, but still it fails with `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException`:

```
    private static String escapeJson(String raw)    {
        String escaped = raw;
        escaped = escaped.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        escaped = escaped.replace("\"", "\\\"");
        escaped = escaped.replace("\b", "\\b");
        escaped = escaped.replace("\f", "\\f");
        escaped = escaped.replace("\n", "\\n");
        escaped = escaped.replace("\r", "\\r");
        escaped = escaped.replace("\t", "\\t");
        escaped = escaped.replace("/", "\\/");
        return escaped;
    }
```

Please let me know if there is any way to make sure characters are well escaped and well handled for json?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong. But manual escaping doesn't look correct at all. It's responsibility of a Gson. Doing it manually is error prone at the very least. For example what you've done is not complete list of characters than need to be escaped. All ascii symbols below 0x20 must be escaped. There are also surrogate escapes.

Comment: If what you see in the text editor differs from what you see in the console after you've read the file the problem must be in the reading file. Could you please show how you do this or better provide MVP for reproducing your problem?

Comment: Make your TSV contain proper _enveloped_ escapes: 1) the first layer for CSV/TSV; 2) the second layer for the enveloped JSON (yeah, double-double backslashes will be good). In your case, the second condition is unmet. Don't ever make manual escaping like this. Additionally, sometimes it is much better to put at least one row of the _original_ CSV/TSV to make sure you haven't lost anything while posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

This one works without any problems;

```
@Test
public void t11(){
    String s = "{\"person\":[{\"initials\":\"J.\",\"name\":\"HEINZERING\"}],\"fullText\":\"R\\\\NTGENSTRAHLEN, Nr. Seiten 34-41, DE; u.a.; \\\"Technische Fortschritte in der NMR-Tomographie\"}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object o = gson.fromJson(s, Object.class);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(o));
}
```

And the output is

```
{"person":[{"initials":"J.","name":"HEINZERING"}],"fullText":"R\\NTGENSTRAHLEN, Nr. Seiten 34-41, DE; u.a.; \"Technische Fortschritte in der NMR-Tomographie"}
```